# How To Import Every Components At Once From React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

As we all know that if we want to work in React Native, then for that we have to import things like this.

```
import { View ,Text } from "react-native";
```

But I want to know is there any way that we don't have to import these components again and again from React Native, because I am a web developer who want to become android app developer right now. And as we all know that we don't need to import such tags again and again in HTML.

Can we do something like this in React Native?

```
import * from "react-native";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as ReactNative from 'react-native'


<ReactNative.Text>Text component</ReactNative.Text>;
```

If I'm not mistaken you want to achieve such behavior?

Comment: Actually i want to use Text , View , StyleSheet  without importing them from 'react-native' is this possible ?

Comment: No you can not, they are not native components such as <div/>, <section/> etc. That's you anyway need to import them from the react-native library.